# Is $\cot(\cot(\cot(\cdots\cot1)\cdots))$ always defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider sequence $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=\cot a_n$. Is $a_n$ always defined?

Numerical evaluation suggests this conjecture is true.

I have proved a weak version of this question: for a fixed $n$ and $a_1=x$, the measure of $x$ such that $a_n$ is not defined is 0.

**Proof**
There is a bijection between $\{x|a_n\text{ is not defined}\}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{n-1}$, the set is countable, hence the measure is 0.

Does anyone have some idea on the original question?

Comment: @Blue I think the brackets can be ignored?

Comment: What does it mean for a real number to be meaningful?

Comment: I mean the situation like $\cot0$ will never happen.

Comment: @KemonoChen I think this is called "defined" (?)

Comment: @KemonoChen: In this context, I think it's better to use the parentheses. Otherwise, the expression looks like it might be an erroneously-formatted product of some kind. (That's actually what I thought it was, at first sight.)

Comment: @Tianlalu thanks for correcting word choosing.

Comment: I think it would be **truly remarkable** if $a_n$ just happens to hit $\pi\mathbb Z$.  Therefore, I feel safe in asserting that this does not occur.  But it also seems unlikely that there is a proof; unless perhaps there is some geometric interpretation for the sequence $a_n$.